# Python List Comprehensions try

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a list that looks like this:

```
target = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '...', '1458', 'Next']
```

I am wondering, is there a one-line list comprehension solution to find the highest number in the list:

I have tried:

```
max([int(num) for num in text])
```

...but it seems like some of the text cannot be converted and there is no try except in the list comprehension.

I CAN ONLY ACCEPT A ONE LINE SOLUTION, PLEASE

my code:

```
text = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '...', '1458', 'Next']
print text
max = 0
for num in text:
    try:
        if int(num) > max:
            max = int(num)
    except:
        pass
print max
```

Comment: Why would you accept only one-line solutions?  Do you only write one-line programs?

Comment: @DSM I happen to be in a position that don't share that much code with other people. Short code with clear structure is much easier for me to remember and reuse

Comment: Neither "short code" nor "clear structure" have much to do with "one line".  In fact, because of the way Python works, there are many things which are best done using `try/except` pairs, which can't be crammed into one line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use [`str.isdigit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) to test if the string *can* be converted:

```
max(int(num) for num in text if num.isdigit())
```

A generator expression is enough here, no need to create an intermediary list.

Demo:

```
>>> text = ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '...', '1458', 'Next']
>>> max(int(num) for num in text if num.isdigit())
1458
```

Note that `int()` also tolerates whitespace; if you suspect your input list has whitespace around the numbers, you can add a `str.strip()` call too to widen the net a little:

```
max(int(num) for num in text if num.strip().isdigit())
```

If you need to support signed values too (an initial `-` or `+`) you could try:

```
max(int(num) for num in text if num.strip().lstrip('-+').isdigit() and num.count('-') + num.count('+') <= 1)
```

for an even more exhaustive test. `int()` is a little more tolerant still but this is more than close enough for most cases; if you want to capture each and every possibility you'd have to resort to regular expressions.

Demo:

```
>>> text = [' +2 ', '-3', '     4', '5    ', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '...', '  +1458  ', 'Next']
>>> max(int(num) for num in text if num.strip().lstrip('-+').isdigit() and num.count('-') + num.count('+') <= 1)
1458
```